# Regex to Parse Block of text Similar to Java Properties File Format

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String variable:

```
String text = "
Lots of text...
some random text here
PackageName=com.company.package
more random text here";
```

I thought the Java code to retrieve my package name here would be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PackageName=(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String packageName = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Unfortunately, matcher.find() always returns false.  What am I doing wrong?

Please note, I am **not** trying to retrieve the package name of my class, and **I am not trying to parse a java properties file**.  I am trying to parse some text as stated above, where there is a param=value pair somewhere in the text I need to retrieve.  Thank you.

Comment: Why use regex to parse the properties file when you can use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/PropertiesgetPropertyStringkey.htm use getProperty()

Comment: i am not trying to parse a properties file. i am trying to parse a block of text where part of the text has the same format as a properties file.  i have updated the question to make this more apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the input that you provided :

> String text = "Lots of text..." + "\n" + "String=Value" + "\n" + "PackageName=com.company.package" + "\n" + "String=Value";

The code that YOU wrote:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PackageName=(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String packageName = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(packageName);
}
```

Works fine, it does retrieve the package name.

Unless you have anything to add that will clarify the problem, and what is wrong, then this is not even a question, everything works. :)

Cheers, Eugene.

Comment: for whatever reason, today it wants to work for me.  maybe it was a stale eclipse debugger or something.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be in the `String` lines at the top. You cannot declare a `String` literal over multiple lines in Java, you need to separate them by `\n` characters:

```
String text = "Lots of text...\nString=Value\nPackageName=com.company.package\nString=Value";
```

To make it more readable, you can do this:

```
String text = "Lots of text...\n" 
            + "String=Value\n" 
            + "PackageName=com.company.package\n" 
            + "String=Value";
```

Once that change is made, the code you provide works fine for me on JDK6.

That said, here is the regex slightly improved:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PackageName\\s*=\\s*(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String packageName = matcher.group(1);
}
```

The only change I made was to add `\\s*`: this means any whitespace (or none) so you can put `PackageName = abc` and have it work (note that the regex item itself is actually `\s*` but you have to escape the `\` character in Java).

Answer (score -2):

My java code

```
 String text = "Lots of text... String=Value    PackageName=com.company.package String=Value";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PackageName=(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String packageName = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println(packageName);
        }
```

The result runs :

**com.company.package   String=Value**